# Remove the particular pattern from text using regex in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to remove the "2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     " from text.txt using regex.

```
text.txt
2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart
2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart
2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart
2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart
```

*Expected result:*

```
 asfasnfs: remove datepart
 asfasnfs: remove datepart
 asfasnfs: remove datepart
 asfasnfs: remove datepart
```

* My solution*
To remove date part. I have written below regex:

```
**2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258**
p = '\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}-d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}'

import re
test = re.sub(p,'', text)
```

Pattern p does not work. It gives the text as it is. And I am not sure how to remove the whole part in text using regex.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the backslash \ in front of your first `d` at the beginning of the pattern, so it will match a literal "d" instead of a number.

Comment: I tried it, it is not working.

Comment: Ok, then you should update your code to the correct regex in your question (add the backslash) so that other people know that's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did it just now...

Comment: I see a *forward* slash there, not a backslash.

Comment: Yaa, I did it with backslash.

Comment: Ok, you're also missing a backslash after another `d`, about halfway through. And you may need to escape your forward slashes. Try running your regex through a checker: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
p = '\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}'
test = re.sub(p,'', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for this:

```
^.{53}
```

and replace with blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern only matches the first part of the string. To make that pattern work, you have to escape the dot to match it literally and add a backslash before the `d`:

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}
                  ^                ^
```

To match the part so it would leave your expected result, you could use this pattern after it where `[ \t]+` would match 1+ times a space or tab. If there are no tabs you could use a space only.

```
[ \t]+\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z0-9]{12}[ \t]+
```

The full pattern could look like:

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}[ \t]+\d{4}[ \t]+[A-Z0-9]{12}[ \t]+
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kUakCb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oWvuCY)